# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at normSchema

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

form.customer.json

```
{
      "key": "profileDetails.address.addressDetails[].country.masterCode",
      "ngModelOptions": { "updateOn": "change blur" },
      "autopopulateTo": [                    
       "serviceUser.serviceUser.address.addressDetails[0].country.masterCode"
       ],
       "validationMessage": {
         "1": "This field is required"
       }
}  


 {
            "key": "profileDetails.address.addressDetails[].province.masterCode",
            "reload": {
            "service": "CustomerProfileProvinceLoader",
            "fetchAction": "load",
               "updateAction": "updateValues",
            "watch": [               
           "profileDetails.address.addressDetails[arrayIndex].country.masterCode"
            ]},
            "autopopulateTo": [                      
          "serviceUser.serviceUser.address.addressDetails[0].province.masterCode"
        ],
        "ngModelOptions": {
            "updateOn": "change blur"
        },
        "disabled": "!model.profileDetails.address.addressDetails[arrayIndex].country.masterCode",
        "validationMessage": {
            "1": "This field is required"
        }
}
```

schema.customer.json

```
                             "province": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "masterCode": {
                                            "title": "Province",
                                            "description": "Select province",
                                            "type": [
                                                "null",
                                                "string"
                                            ],
                                            "enum": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "masterCode"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "country": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "masterCode": {
                                            "title": "Country",
                                            "description": "Select country",
                                            "type": [
                                                "null",
                                                "string"
                                            ],
                                            "enum": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "masterCode"
                                    ]
                                }
```

Data:

```
{
                "code" : "Country1", 
                "name" : "Country1", 
                "default" : "Y", 
                "provinces" : {
                    "province" : [
                        {
                            "code" : "P1", 
                            "name" : "PROVINCE1", 
                            "cities" : {
                                "city" : [
                                    {
                                        "code" : "1234", 
                                        "name" : "city1", 
                                        "default" : "Y"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "code" : "P2", 
                            "name" : "PROVINCE2", 
                            "cities" : {
                                "city" : [
                                    {
                                        "code" : "c1", 
                                        "name" : "city2"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "code" : "c2", 
                                        "name" : "city3"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                ]
          }
```

}

Here in the above code country field is a dropdown. whenever I change the country field value "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" is produced. and the province field which should be deselected, is not happening.

Problem is with the data which I load into country field. Because whenever I load the above data(which consists of provinces.province), error was thrown.

Comment: This is not a complete code to showcase problem.

Comment: It also doesn't look like a valid angular-schema-form definition?

Comment: My bad, thought problem lies in the form. Figured out, problem lies in the data. because whenever i load simple data, it was working fine. Problem occurs, when i put provinces in the data

Comment: @SoujanyaDivi please share your html also